# Can't run Self 4.4 on OS X

Tags: self

I followed the instructions at http://selflanguage.org/download/index.html for installing Self 4.4 on my OS X box.  The Self-4.4.pkg installed without issue, but there is no "...small shell script at /usr/bin/Self".

The files that are supposed to be in /Libarary/Self are there, but double-clicking on them does nothing.  Double clicking on the Snapshots is equally futile.

How do I get this thing to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently is a bug in the Installer that should get fixed soon.
In the meantime,

- you can create the file /usr/bin/Self yourself with the following content

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  /Library/Self/0/Self.app/Contents/MacOS/Self $@
  ```
- you can use the actual Self executable directly: `/Library/Self/0/Self.app/Contents/MacOS/Self`

(in both cases, you should use the `-s` command-line switch when you want to load a snapshot)

- you can try the experimental OS X Self starter (see http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/self-interest/message/2856) that is available for download at http://selflanguage.org/files/releases/4.5/experimental/SelfVM-30Mar12.zip